# -[__NSDictionaryM intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13f26a60

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

i am trying to fetch record for core database but it is giving me given below error.

**Error** -[__NSDictionaryM intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13f26a60

on line

```
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Here is full code of fetch request.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [delegate managedObjectContext];


NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (serverId IN %@)", a];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
id results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"results %@",results);
// error handling code
[request release];
```

Comment: I don't see a call to `intValue` anywhere in your code.

Comment: At runtime, sometime object gets converted to someother type put you guessing. This happend here too.

Comment: If `serverId` is int value, then you probably need to change `NOT (serverId IN %@)` to `NOT (serverId IN %d)`

Comment: Is `a` an NSArray? What does it contain?

Comment: serverId is integer when i change to NOT (serverId IN %d) then it gives following error -[__NSCFNumber countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xba794c0

Comment: nsarray contain id in string format because i cannot add integer in nsarray

Comment: You add NSNumbers in NSArrays, not primitive integer types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *assume* that your array `a` does not contain numbers, but dictionaries, for example:

```
NSArray *a = @[
                  @{@"serverId" : @"2", ...},
                  @{@"serverId" : @"4", ...}
              ];
```

because that would cause exactly the error message that you got.

You have to create an array containing only the "serverId" numbers, and use that in the predicate:

```
NSArray *serverIds = [a valueForKey:@"serverId"];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (serverId IN %@)", serverIds];
```

Comment: do you know that you are a genius.

Comment: i was in a hurry while typing this code due to which i made a silly mistake of giving wrong variable to predicate

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as Developer but in my case the error was that I was using the wrong conversion specifier. My array contained NSNumber objects and I was using `%ld` as the conversion specifier. I did change the conversion specifier to `%@` as Martin R suggested and it worked like a charm.

Hope this helps someone.